# for in loop to find property

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop, console.log

I have created a for in loop and am trying to understand why when I run it, the console logs 2x "We got it." It seems like if I was looping through you would only want it to log once if it found the property once.

Also im a JS newbie so if you have any feedback on my formatting that is always appreciated. Happy Holidays!

```
var obj = {
  company: 'planters',
  peanuts: 'plain'
};

for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('peanuts')) {
    console.log('We got it');
  } else {
    console.log("We cant find it");
  }
};
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the current key in your `if` statement.

Comment: on a different note, you don't want for/in, you actually want `Object.keys(obj).forEach(...)`. for/in generally requires you first do an `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` check to see if you're dealing with a local property or an inherited one. That requirement (and problem) does not happen for Object.keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that is happening is you are looping it for 2 iterations (which is the length of the object) and looking if object has property `peanuts`, which is true in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is unnecessary.  You're not using `key`.  It's just equivalent to running the body of the for loop the number of times of keys there are in the object (and parents).

Try

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  // you mean this
    console.log('We got ', key);
  } else {
    console.log("We cant find it");
  }
};
```

to see what's going on here better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a specific key, you have to compare it with `key`.

```
var found = false;
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key == 'peanuts') {
        console.log('We got it');
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    console.log("We can't find it");
}
```